# Decrypting Zend 2 Block Cipher encryption using PHP or Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, zend-framework, encryption

I was asked to create an API using the Laravel framework on an existing Web application. The web application uses the Zend 2 Block Cipher encryption to encrypt user password. The previous developer who developed the site has already moved on and I need to create a service to verify the user's password in the API. The problem is I can't crack Zend's encryption. I even tried using the PHP mcrypt function but I'm getting this error.

```
mcrypt_decrypt(): Size of key is too large for this algorithm
```

This is a bit odd but is there anyway I can decrypt Zend's encryption using just plain PHP? Or is there a work around here? I can't change the current web application as it is being used.

Here is the sample code of the encryption:

```
use Zend\Crypt\BlockCipher;

class Encryption {
    private $_cipher = null;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->_cipher = BlockCipher::factory('mcrypt',array('algo'=>'aes'));
        $this->_cipher->setKey('fltjXW05820D[1(Z5SknJBZ12goBbyK<*271biqT5"j$WvA2JCycgA"{UIe6qJ2');
    }

    public function encrypt($plainText){
        return $this->_cipher->encrypt($plainText);
    }

    public function decrypt($enctyptedData){
        return $this->_cipher->decrypt($enctyptedData);
    }
}
```

Any advice by the experts?

Thank you in advance. Sorry I'm a beginner in Laravel and Zend.

Comment: Your error message says it all.  Your key is too long.  MCrypt uses a 256bit key (32 characters).  Maybe the key you have has been hashed in some way to disguise it?

Comment: Your key is 11 characters too long ... interestingly enough - there are 11 punctuation characters at the beginning of the key you've tried to use.  Maybe the answer is that simple?  Try getting rid of them.

Comment: Sorry wrong key. I've pasted the correct one. Yes I think there is some hashing or padding that was done on the key but my superiors have said they just used the Zend cipher. Any more ideas?

Comment: It's still too long ... and (un)fortunately a cipher just wouldn't be any good if you could extract its key from anything that has been enciphered by it.  You need the correct key.  Have you got access to the code which encrypted the passwords to begin with?  Perhaps the key will be there - and if the key is hashed or padded, perhaps too will be the answer of how to make it usable.

Comment: As for raw PHP workarounds - Zend is just wrapping [PHP Mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) - and there's not much more you could do with that.

Comment: The Zend Framework is pretty modular. Why can't you simply use that part?